# Howto make a LibreOffice simple chart

Tags: libreoffice, xls

I have to say that is almost the first time I deal with an .xls file

I have a sigle column with simple alphanumeric datas. They may be numbers or words. For instance you may have a book written in a sincle column with a single word per cell

I would like to have a bar-chart counting the occurrences of any single word

I tried to inserd a chart and play with options but no way...

Is there a simple, say two-click way to do it? (I'm sure there is!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/41969/create-chart-from-values-single-column/.

For example, start with the following data in A1 through A6.

```
Words
~~~~~~~~~~
apple
banana
cantaloupe
banana
apple
```

Mark the Column and choose *Insert -> Pivot Table*

1. Drag and drop "Words" to *Row Fields*.
2. Drag and drop "Words" to *Data Fields*.  Double-click and change *Function* to `Count`.
3. Hit OK.

Select the Pivot Table data and go to *Insert -> Chart*.

[image: chart]